# How to create different reference for each for..loop element in Angular 7

Tags: typescript, angular7

Please find my below stakblitz link.

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-sbkgbf

I have placed one button to left of each dropdown to open the respective dropdown. I opened the dropdown programmatically by creating reference of mat-select via @ViewChild.  My issue here is, only the ABCD dropdown is opening for all the button clicks. But when I tried to open the dropdown directly by clicking it, I could be able to open each of them respectively. So I could understand that for all the mat-option that is being created in the for...loop has the same reference in the typescript. How will I be able to create separate references for each of them, so that when I click the buttons, the respective dropdown is opened. Or Am I approaching my requirement in a wrong way? If so is there any other way we can achieve this. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Okay I found the answer. I just passed local reference from html via click event and handled the opening of mat-select in typescript.

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-sbkgbf